# CkEditor Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ckeditor

I want to use CKEditor.

I have currently install CKEditor using npm

So it is installed in node_modules folder

My folder structure is like

> app --> index.js
>
> node_modules -->ckeditor -->...

and I have required it in index.js

also set variable  before initialization of library

```
 var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '../node_modules/ckeditor'
```

still getting the dir error

suggest some help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '../node_modules/ckeditor';
```

to

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '../node_modules/ckeditor/';
```

Don't forget the trailing slash on the directory

And try putting the window declaration above your import of ckeditor

Check out this link for more information: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Specifying_the_Editor_Path

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is working .. perfect. but is there  a better way to define CKEDITOR_BASEPATH because defining a variable in window object is not best practice

Comment: Unfortunately no or atleast not that I'm aware of. A quick check in the source code shows the basepath function looking for window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH | '', if there is no basepath set, it falls back onto its default which breaks for some of us.

Answer (score 3):

For others with this problem (since it still persists as of the newest version at this time), if you have self-hosted the CKEditor script in your solution (for example for a classic ASP.NET application) and you do not have all the localization files of the plugin in your CKEditor folder, that can cause this issue to happen. I tried using NoToBagels solution, but it changed nothing for me.

We for example only had the `en.js` file in our `/CKEditor/lang/` folder, and the bug occurred when a user that had both english and danish as his browser languages. CKEditor tried to automatically set the language of the editor to Danish, and tried to load the `/CKEditor/lang/da.js` file, which did not exist (which caused a 404 error). Adding the following to the config.js file fixed the problem for us:

`config.language = 'en';`

[setting config.language](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/uilanguage.html) ensures that the language of the editor is set to english instead of it being auto detected.

Answer (score 0):

NoToBagels fixed one of my problems. I also had the variable being set in jQuery doc ready which was registering CKEDITOR_BASEPATH too late. Moving it to run as soon as the javascript file loaded solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET devs, I was also stuck in this for a while too. The problem was VS was not adding the CKEDITOR folders to my build project.
I added CKEDITOR folders to my project and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error in Ang 7.2 project, when trying to use ckeditor4-angular and ckeditor4.
Resolved by putting entire ckeditor4 folder into src/assets and adding

`<head> <script src="assets/ckeditor4/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"> </head>`
in index.html
Rest of config and setup same as https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor4-angular